# pandas merge all files in the same directory

Tags: python, pandas, merge, glob

I'm trying to `pd.merge` to merge all files in the same directory to one file. Here's an example of the inputs, they are excel files in the same directory:

```
df1:
A     B     C
a     1     dog
b     0     dog
c     2     cat

df2:
A     D     E
a     2     bird
b     4     lion
c     1     cat

df3:
A     F      G
a     1     seal
b     20    raccoon
c     2     squirrel
```

Here is the output I want:

```
A     B     C      D     E     F     G     
a     1     dog    2     bird  1     seal
b     0     dog    4     lion  20    raccoon
c     2     cat    1     cat   2     squirrel
```

My code:

```
  files = glob.glob('/Users/files/*.xlsx')
  all_data = pd.merge(files, how='left')
```

Error:

```
  TypeError: merge() missing 1 required positional argument: 'right'
```

Is `merge` only working for merging two files?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: pd.merge needs dataframes not filenames.

Comment: read file into list  pd.concat rather than `merge` , PS: set A as index

Comment: @JohnGalt thx for your reminder, that's  a helpful point.

Comment: @Wen thx! You mean `pd.Dataframe.set_index()`?

Comment: I think @JohnGalt Already made my comment became an answer, you can check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pd.concat`, with index set on `A`

```
In [20]: pd.concat(
            [pd.read_excel(f).set_index('A') for f in glob.glob('*.xlsx')],
            axis=1).reset_index()
Out[20]:
   A  B    C  D     E   F         G
0  a  1  dog  2  bird   1      seal
1  b  0  dog  4  lion  20   raccoon
2  c  2  cat  1   cat   2  squirrel
```